# Distinct the collection in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the  collection

From the collection the column name ma_position_value  should not contain the same value

For Example

If the collection have 5 records, The column  ma_position_value   should not contain the same value from all 5 records...but it can contain same value for 2 or 3 or 4 records from the collection Atleast one column value should change.

So the main intension is ALL 5 records should not contain same value.Any one should get different value.So if all 5 is same I tried to throw a message

So I have just write a bool to return it if it is change

```
bool lblMa = false;
lblMa = ibusCalcWiz.iclbMssPaServiceSummary
        .Where(lbusMssPaServiceSummary => lbusMssPaServiceSummary.icdoSummary.ma_position_value.IsNotNullOrEmpty()).Distinct().Count() > 1;
```

But it is always return true.

Comment: FYI, you can avoid checking more items than necessary by using `query.Skip(1).Any()` instead of `query.Count() > 1`.  It doesn't matter for a collection with only 5 records, but if you end up working with larger collections, it can make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first one, and check if they are all equal:

```
// Only works if the collection is non-empty!
string first_ma_position_value = ibusCalcWiz.iclbMssPaServiceSummary.First().ma_position_value;
bool allTheSame = ibusCalcWiz.iclbMssPaServiceSummary
   .All(lbusMssPaServiceSummary.icdoSummary.ma_position_value == first_ma_position_value);
```

or you can do the distinct, as you originally wanted, but on the value of the column instead of on the objects

```
bool allTheSame = ibusCalcWiz.iclbMssPaServiceSummary
               .Select(lbusMssPaServiceSummary => lbusMssPaServiceSummary.icdoSummary.ma_position_value)
               .Distinct()
               .Count() == 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just select distinct `ma_position_value` property values:

```
bool allSame = ibusCalcWiz.iclbMssPaServiceSummary
                          .Select(i => i.ma_position_value)
                          .Distinct()
                          .Count() == 1;
```

HINT: Do not use long variable names in lambda expressions. There is a rule of thumb - the bigger scope of variable usage, the bigger should be name. If scope is very small (lambda expression) then name should be very small (single letter is enough).

Comment: As per Mike Strobel's comment to the question, it can be expensive to do `query.Count()`. Instead of `query.Count() == 1` one can use, for example, `query.Take(2).Count() == 1`. That should be faster if the `query` yields very many items.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen agree, in case of performance issues it's better to use `Skip(1).Any()`

Comment: Yes, but it depends on whether you mean `Count > 1` or you mean `Count != 1` (or their negations of course). Hope you understand what I mean. So, `q.Skip(1).Any()` will also be `false` on an empty source `q`, not only on a one-element source.